# Como fazer um FOR aninhado?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for

tô abrindo dois arquivos, um é um texto, e o outro é uma lista. Tô querendo através de for aninhado verificar quantas vezes cada item da lista aparece no texto.

Fiz assim:

```
arquivo = open('texto.txt', 'r')
lista = open('lista.txt', 'r')

for item in lista:
   i = 0;
   for linha in arquivo:
      if item[0:-1] in linha:
    i += 1
    print(item)
    print(i)
```

Só que dessa forma ele só tá mostrando o primeiro item da lista e quantas vezes ele aparece. Por exemplo, se tiver a palavra 'iPhone 6' na minha lista e ela aparece 3 vezes no texto, ele da essa saída:

```
iPhone 6
1
iPhone 6
2
iPhone 6
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lista = ['iPhone 6', 'Apple', 'Android','Samsung']
text = '''
iPhone 6 é um dispostivo da Apple.
iPhone 6 não é da Samsung, iPonhe 6 é da Apple
'''

for l in lista:
    print (l,':',text.count(l))

iPhone 6 : 2
Apple : 2
Android : 0
Samsung : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa tirar o `print` que exibe o valor do primeiro laço de dentro do segundo:

```
for item in lista:
   i = 0;
   print(item)
   for linha in arquivo:
       if item[0:-1] in linha:
          i += 1
       print(i)
```

Assim ele exibirá o item do primeiro laço uma vez e depois todos os itens do segundo:

```
iPhone 6
1
2
3
```